# How to remap Wii U Pro controller buttons?

Tags: release-loki, settings, bluetooth, games

I connected a Wii U Pro controller to Loki via Bluetooth. It works perfectly but the mapping is correct, like the Nintendo controller it is, which is not good for me! I want the button mapping to work like an XBOX 360's controller (A on bottom, B  on right, etc).

Is there any way to manage controllers on elementary and remap their button layouts? Thanks in advance. C:

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the game uses the configurations: if the game uses SDL (FEZ, for example), you can try to modify the gamecontrollerdb.txt, or you can create an environment variable with a new mapping. Check this site: http://generalarcade.com/gamepadtool/

Usually, emulators allow to remap the controller, you can check the settings in the application

But if you want to map the keyboard to the joystick, i recommend Qjoypad

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never tried this but I heard that this should work for most controllers:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/ubuntu-xbox-controller-support-xboxdrv-driver

Edit:
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! Unfortunately, it did not work at all and it also installed a lot of packages aside from the xboxdrv one whose name I can't remember and now I can't remove them. :(

Also, I tried everything I could to re-map the buttons, but it turns out that the controller is recognized as a proper Nintendo controller instead of an XBOX controller, so it keeps saying that there are no xbox devices connected and thus I cannot remap anything. Thank you for the response, though. :)